# How to add a space in a string at a specific position

Tags: flutter, dart

How to set space after letter,

example:

`String abc = 05:12AM;`

`String abc = 5:12PM;`

`String abc = 12:12AM;`

`String abc = 1:12PM;`

I want to like this result: **05:12 AM**

I tried this way, but not working.

```
String a = abc.replaceAll(RegExp('[a-zA-Z]'), '');
```

Comment: Are you creating the values of those strings or you have no control over their creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating the values of those strings with some date format, you probably want to add the space when you are formatting those strings. For example, using `intl` package, you could do this:

```
String abc = DateFormat('HH:mm a').format(DateTime.now()); // 05:12 AM
```

---

If you have no control over the creations of those strings and you know for sure that you always receive AM or PM at the end, you could do this:

```
String a = '${abc.substring(0, abc.length - 2)} ${abc.substring(abc.length - 2)}';
```

or

```
String a = '${abc.replaceRange(abc.length-2, abc.length-2, ' ')}';
```

---

If it's possible that those strings come without AM or PM, you could do this:

```
String a = abc.replaceFirstMapped(RegExp('AM|PM'), (m) => ' ${m.group(0)}');
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you only want to move 2 characters to the right with adding space. First u need to get the last two character with subString, then remove last two characters with subString. Then use + to add them with space. Code :

```
String abc = '05:12AM';
String lastTwo = abc.substring(abc.length-2,abc.length);
String removedLastTwo = abc.substring(0,abc.length-2);
String a = removedLastTwo + ' ' + lastTwo;

print('lastTwo = ' + lastTwo);
print('removedLastTwo = ' + removedLastTwo);
print('a = ' + a);
```

Answer (score 1):

```dart
  String abc = '1:12PM';
  String a = abc.replaceAllMapped(RegExp('[a-zA-Z]+'), (m) => ' ${m.group(0)}');
```

or maybe like this to ensure you're splitting number and characters:

```dart
  String a = abc.replaceAllMapped(RegExp('(\\d)([a-zA-Z]+)'), (m) => '${m.group(1)} ${m.group(2)}');
```

There's also *replaceFirstMapped* method